# Can a realtor show my apartment at will, with notice?

Tags: rent, kansas

My apartment is for sale by its owner, who I'm currently renting from.  The owner uses a management company and I deal with that company to pay rent, have things fixed, etc.  I've never seen or talked to the apartment owner.  The owner is hiring a realtor to help sell the apartment (to someone else; we are leaving after our lease.)  This realtor visited and said they'd like to show the apartment over the next few months, before our lease ends, and implied that there could be many showings.

My contract is very simple.  There's no provision for the management company to enter the property even with notice, though I assume there's some law that allows them to do so.

My question is, do I have to let the realtor in with notice?  What if they're with the manager?  If they wish to do open houses and frequent tours (which they've implied they'd like to), do I have any rights other than obtaining 24 hour notice?  I reiterate that there's nothing about this in my very simple renter's contract.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, but not without notice

[KS Stat § 58-2557 (2015)](https://law.justia.com/codes/kansas/2015/chapter-58/article-25/section-58-2557/)

> **58-2557. Landlord's right to enter; limitations.** (a) The landlord shall have the right to enter the dwelling unit at reasonable hours, after reasonable notice to the tenant, in order to ... exhibit the dwelling unit to prospective or actual purchasers, ...

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer.  The section you cited is pretty small with minimal clauses.  Does this mean that the realtor (with the landlord) could visit several times per day until they sell the unit?  Can I demand that the landlord be with the realtor, when he shows the apartment?  As of now it sounds like the realtor expects to come on his own.

Comment: Is several times a day reasonable? If you’re at work and they only come then - probably. The realtor IS the landlord due to being the landlord’s agent - it’s highly unusual for a landlord to attend a showing.

Comment: The cited law supports this answer, and does not support the answer by @Studoku which is quite simply incorrect.

Comment: @HH the key concept in the law is "reasonable". If the is a dispute it will come down to what a judge or jury thinks is reasonable under the circumstances. Common practice in the industry can also be considered in determining what is reasonable.

Comment: There would be a reasonable suspicion if there are multiple showings per day, multiple days a week, that it is not for selling the apartment, but for harassing the tenant. I'd suspect that doing six viewings at six different times is not reasonable, when all six potential buyers could be invited at the same time.

Answer (score -4):

A tenant has the right to *quiet enjoyment* of the property. This does not need to be specified in the contract.

This means that even if the landlord or representative gives notice, this could potentially violate that.

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this answer. In the absence of a comment, the poster cannot improve the answer, others cannot use the reasons to write better answers, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the answer. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: Dis you mean "gives noticew" rather than "gets notice'"in the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: While the above is, to the best of my understanding, true in general common law, it seems to be incorrect under the specific Kansas statute cited by Dale. (KS Stat § 58-2557 (2015)) There are probably similar provisions in the laws elsewhere, and in many cases a lease will cover such issues (although it doesn't seem to in this case). You may wish to edit this answer.

Comment: The answer **you** gave seems to be simply incorrect, as revealed by the law cited in the answer by Dale. Do you plan to correct the answer you gave? Dale's intentions are irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I wish that too but it it is neither a requirement or expected on any Stack Exchange site. Users are free to exercise their vote as they see fit and are not expected to give an answer. Viva democracy.

Comment: @Dale I know that. But I am free to point out the value of explaining downvotes, and to politely request users to do so. They are free not to respond.

Comment: @DavidSiegel sure. I know you know that but my comment is for those users who don’t and may draw the opposite conclusion from your comment.

Comment: I fail to see how the other answer contradicts mine.

Comment: The other answer cites a specific law which says "The landlord shall have the right to enter the dwelling unit at reasonable hours, after reasonable notice to the tenant,..." This answer cites the common-law right of "quiet enjoyment" and says that  "even if the landlord or representative gives notice" that right might be violated, ignoring the specific and overriding right in the statute. It also does not cite any source on what constitutes "quiet enjoyment".

Comment: the notice requirement does not violate quiet enjoyment, but it limits it to *every time but for when notice is given*.

Comment: This answer is true and correct, but completely unhelpful. The OP understands that it may or may not violate a right that they have. They need to know when and whether it does or doesn't, and this answer just says that it might or might not.