# Are peers of landlord-appointed agents also landlord-appointed agents?

Tags: rental-property, real-estate, kansas

This is related to two of my previous questions: [Can a landlord appoint agents at will?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/can-a-landlord-appoint-agents-at-will/64616#64616) and [Can a landlord appoint agents at will?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/can-a-landlord-appoint-agents-at-will/64616#64616)

The owner of my apartment has hired a realtor to sell it.  According to the answers in the above linked questions the realtor can access the apartment at will.  This realtor is wanting other realtors that he's somehow affiliated with to show the apartment as well.  Are these realtors also considered agents of the landlord (and thus have legal access to the apartment)?  It sounds like there will be several people coming and going at will to show the apartment.

Edit to include more information that I've just been provided: The realtor appointed by the owner is part of the city Board of Realtors, and the realtors all cooperate in showing properties.  The realtor tells me that the "listing agreement" with the owner of the property "includes the allowance of showing to the other professional realtors".  It sounds like there will be a lot of realtors coming in and out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like the person asking the question no longer has a question as it has been edited.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm the person who asked this question and I still have a question.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

### It’s [agents all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

1. I can appoint an agent.
2. That agent can appoint an agent who will also be my agent.
3. Repeat step 2 as often as necessary.

Of course, an agency agreement can prohibit sub-agency but the details of that will generally not be publicly known.

Which is the reason that agency law includes the concept of [apparent authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_authority) which means that if a reasonable third party would believe the person was an agent and has authority to bind their principal, they do. This is why you can assume that the person at the grocery check out is an agent of the store and has the authority to sell you groceries.

Comment: Upvote for the turtles

Comment: The other professional realtors and their clients are technically invitees of the agent, and not subagents.