# Realtor consistently does not provide notice before showing apartment

Tags: rent, kansas

I asked this awhile back: [Can a realtor show my apartment at will, with notice?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64608/can-a-realtor-show-my-apartment-at-will-with-notice)

I am renting an apartment that the owners are trying to sell.

I am out of town.  The realtor entered and showed the apartment (without directly escorting those viewing it, though perhaps that's unrelated).  I contacted them and told them, kindly, that as far as I understood they were required to give me advanced notice.  The realtor apologized and agreed to give notice in the future.

The realtor (or an agent of the realtor, that's currently unclear) has entered again without providing notice.  What can I do about this?

Comment: The realtor doesn't work for you and has no obligation to you: so put your demand in writing, and deliver it to the landlord, who will then pass order on the the realtor.

Comment: @user6726 neither does a burglar work for me. The contract states 24 hour notice. If someone violates this, even inadvertently, and whether or not they have an obligation to me, I assume that some law has been broken.  Do I assume wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The realtor (or an agent of the realtor, that's currently unclear) has entered again without providing notice. What can I do about this?

Kansas statute [58-2571(b)](http://www.kslegislature.org/li/b2021_22/statute/058_000_0000_chapter/058_025_0000_article/058_025_0071_section/058_025_0071_k/) provides that "*an unlawful entry, or a lawful entry in an unreasonable matter*" entitles the tenant to "*injunctive relief to prevent the recurrence of the conduct, or may terminate the rental agreement*" in addition to recovery of actual damages. You can file suit in district court. See section [58-2542](http://www.kslegislature.org/li/b2021_22/statute/058_000_0000_chapter/058_025_0000_article/058_025_0042_section/058_025_0042_k/).

I presume you have evidence of the realtor's unlawful entries. But hopefully you also have or can get the realtor's admission & promise is *in writing*, since that would further reinforce your legal position.

Comment: I do have video of everything, which is how I know the details.  I have no problem with them showing the place.  I just want my 24 hours notice.